# Can shatan show miracles to fool other religion's people?

Tags: shaitan, other-religions, miracles

We can see many reports of people reporting seeing Jesus and Mary and many other miracles like the Fatima sun miracle in 1917 in Portugal when people saw solar rays changing colour.

So when I read this these, I am sure that it is shatan. But it's troubling me because I have not heard in hadith saying shatan does miracles to fool other religion's peoples.  I thought shatan does things to Muslims only. Can somebody please explain if this is done by shatan only?

Answer (score 1):

Satan is incapable of showing miracles. He, however, might be able to resort to trickery as was done by the courtiers of Pharao, when challenging prophet Moses. This kind of trickery is possible even by ordinary human beings having certain knowledge.

Miracles are performed only by the Prophets (with the sanction of God).
Karamats are performed by the saints, people of God. (with the sanction of God). Rest is all trickery (which may also be called Magic).